# How to exclude parameters from AI log?

Tags: azure, parameters, azure-application-insights

I would like to exclude some parameters (e.g. city, userId, app role, ...) from traces and dependencies logs in Application Insights.

Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to change the value of userId / app role to empty. Then in the AI logs, **city, userId, app role** will be removed automatically.

I test it with a **.net core web app**:

1.Add a **MyTelemetryInitializer** class to the web project:

```
    public class MyTelemetryInitializer: ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            //only apply for Trace and Dependency
            if (telemetry is TraceTelemetry || telemetry is DependencyTelemetry)
            {
                telemetry.Context.User.Id = "";
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleInstance = "";
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "";
            }
        }    
    }
```

2.In the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method, register the custom telemetry initializer:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //other code

            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```

3.In the HomeController.cs, create a TelemetryClient to send telemetry data:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            client.TrackTrace("0624-2 index: this is a trace message!!!");
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            client.TrackTrace("0624-2 about: this is a trace message!!!");

            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            client.TrackTrace("0624-2 contact: this is a trace message!!!");
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
   }
```

4.After running the project, wait for a few minutes, then nav to azure portal -> your app insights -> search page, check the properties of the trace messages:

[image]